How to transform geoJSON 31983 into 4326 in Openlayers
I have code in Openlayers, which allows you to draw geometries on a layer and then download the file in geoJson format.
Here's the code:
function downloadGeoJSON(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], { type: contentType });
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}

var json = new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeatures(vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures(), {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' 
});

downloadGeoJSON(json, 'my_layer.geojson', 'text/plain');

Note: in the file, the features are saved with geographic SRC 4326, units in degree.
Then I can upload geoJson file. When the file was created in the Openlayers application, the download works correctly.
However, this file may have been created in QGis, with SRC 31983 with the unit in meters. In this case, how should I resolve it?
I need to convert to 4326 units in degrees, but I can't.
This is an example of geometry that is in file 31983
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 342273.613602064666338, 7384707.507063377648592 ] }
This is an example of geometry that is in file 4326
"type":"Point","coordinates":[-46.526534460937505,-23.653072477438627]}
Here is the upload code:
myFile.files[0].text().then(function (text) {
   vector_source.addFeatures(
    new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(text, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                          featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' }) 
});

I need to convert the 31983 file for the upload to work
